# Unable to remove 301 redirect for wordpress wp-admin on nginx

Tags: nginx, wordpress, 301-redirect

Unable to remove 301 redirect for wordpress wp-admin on nginx. The homepage seems fine

I’ve tried almost everything

- Disabling plugins by renaming the plugin directory
- Removing the redirect_canoncial in functions.php
- Even restored an ebs snapshot taken prior to change

The ouput for curl –I http://www.example.com/wp-admin is 301 moved permanently.
I’m using cloudfront and my server default file below

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try disabling all plugins at once? or in a serialized manner, i understand the repercussions involved on doing so, but just cross validating.

Comment: i disabled them all at once by renaming the plugins directory

Comment: alright,   
1. have you validated the wp-config for any force redirects?  
2. check the corresponding database for any redirect rules   
3. where exactly is it getting redirected?

Comment: There are no force redirects on wp-config. Also which table and filed do i check for the redirect rules on the db?

Comment: well that depends, so could also let me know **3. where exactly is it getting redirected?** like is it doing a http:// to https:// or is it landing on any distinct page or the home page itself

Comment: It's being redirected to https://

Comment: It's being redirected to https:// www.example.com/wp-admin

Answer (score 1):

This is a redirection to TLS i.e. `Location: https://www.example.com/wp-admin`. It isn't done in the server configuration, but in `function auth_redirect()`, found in `wp-includes/pluggable.php` lines 997-1064, more specifically in lines 1012-1020:

```
// If https is required and request is http, redirect
if ( $secure && !is_ssl() && false !== strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') ) {
    if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );
        exit();
    } else {
        wp_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        exit();
    }
}
```

This is controlled by `force_ssl_admin()`, enabled by adding `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` constant to `wp-config.php`. If the constant is not defined, it defaults to `false` unless the `siteurl` has `https://` (see `wp_ssl_constants()` in `wp-includes/default-constants.php` lines 284-304).

*Source code line numbers are from current WordPress 4.9.8 and may vary on future versions.*

Admin & login page redirections to TLS are not harmful and you **should have them enabled for security**. Current best practice is to have all sites protected with TLS i.e. `https://www.example.com/` as the siteurl.

Comment: I've added FORCE_SSL_ADMIN to wp-config.php and updated the siteurl on options table to https but i still receive the 301. Any reason why my ebs restore did not take things back to the pre 301 redirect state?

Comment: Only `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);` would disable the redirection, but that only solves the problem you **think** you have, actually causing more problems than it solves.

Comment: i've just tried define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false) and this hasn't stopped the redirection either

Comment: Have you removed all cookies, too? The second test in `auth_redirect()` is whether the user has requested the site to have SSL enabled, and this information is saved in a cookie.

Comment: But really: you should not try to disable TLS. You should try to enable it, instead.

Comment: I've cleared all cookies. I agree with you regarding TLS but right now i'm just trying to regain access to wp-admin dashboard

Comment: Try commenting out `wp_redirect(...` lines from `auth_redirect()`.

Comment: commented out wp_redirect(... lines from auth_redirect() still no luck

Comment: I've identified what is causing the redirect but i don't know what led to it. It appears that nginx was looking for a file /usr/share/nginx/html/wp-admin/index.html. I created a wp-admin folder with an index.html there which stopped the 301 redirection. i've since deleted both and the there's no more 301. Now i get a 404 error when i access wp-admin and default nginx welcome page for home. Nginx is still looking for a file on this file path /usr/share/nginx/html/wp-admin/index.html. I don't know why it is looking for the wp-login using there since i've not configured it to do so.

Comment: After much reading it looks like the issue is down  to a conflict between the default nginx root which i discovered is /usr/share/nginx and the one modified under site-available/default root directive which reads /var/www/html. No idea how to fix it so that i stop recieving 404 for wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

After much reading it looks like the issue is down to a conflict between the default nginx root which i discovered is /usr/share/nginx and the one modified under site-available/default root directive which reads /var/www/html.

Nginx was looking for a file /usr/share/nginx/html/wp-admin/index.html which did not exist. I created a wp-admin folder with an index.html in /usr/share/nginx which stopped the 301 redirection. 
I've since deleted both and the 301 did not return but then led to a 404 error which i fix by returning to the original site-available/default that came with nginx installation. Once i reloaded nginx things were fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can impersonate by specifying a page that becomes 404 in proxy_pass.

```
location = /wp-admin {
    proxy_pass https://example.com/a;
}
```